# Tibco 8.6 64 bit RVD connection issue

Tags: java, tibco-rv

We have 2 Tomcat 8 servers.  Both are running Java 1.8.

I have a war file deployed on both servers.  It works on 1 server, but not the other.  We can’t figure out the reason why.  The 2 servers should have identical setups.

I am using Tibco 8.6 64 bit on a unix OS. All the library and jar files are contained within the war file.  The exact same war file works on one server, but not the other.

It appears to have an issue connecting to the RV daemon.

The error is not helpful at all.  I don’t have any stack trace statements or anything to investigate. 
I’m getting this thread output with a “Subject” and a few other uninformative lines.  Can anyone help to decipher what this error message means and how to resolve it? 
I’ve tried increasing the timeout – it doesn’t help.

The first 3 lines appear in our working log files, so they're not causing the issue.  But I'm not sure why we don't always see them.

ERROR from log file:

```
2021-10-13 19:00:09 RV: Unable to find configuration file tibrvipm.cfg in PATH
2021-10-13 19:00:10 rvipm: Command line:
2021-10-13 19:00:10 rvipm: Unable to find ticket file tibrv.tkt in PATH

19:00:25,155 jcli ERROR: Thread:[ajp-nio-27541-exec-1] RV listener timed out after 15 seconds**
19:00:25,155 jcli ERROR: Thread:[ajp-nio-27541-exec-1] Subject: _IC.NFD_IC_PROD.WRK.0.API.6.100001**
19:00:25,157 jcli ERROR: Thread:[ajp-nio-27541-exec-1] jmtuser**
19:00:25,157 jcli ERROR: Thread:[ajp-nio-27541-exec-1] 7877733651563330793376777541334E4D654C70444C5554424853653132414D**
19:00:25,157 jcli ERROR: Thread:[ajp-nio-27541-exec-1] 0

Failed connecting to IC server [tcp:nfd-ic-prod2]

ERROR: Server operation timed out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from within, we found the issue which was a mis-configured netmask/broadcast on the main network interface.   Once this was corrected, the application started working properly.

Just wanted to document it here in case anyone else runs into a similar problem someday.